# RunPythonCommand failed unexpectedly when running in Visual Studio

Tags: django, visual-studio-2010, python-3.x

I'm starting to wet my feet with Python using Visual Studio. I installed the Python Tools for Visual Studio, I clicked New Project...selected the DJango WebProject template, and it generated some files. At this point, normally, in Visual Studio you should be able to launch the app to give you a simple example. But instead I quickly get a compile error saying:

> Error 1   The "RunPythonCommand" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The parameter is incorrect
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
>      at Microsoft.PythonTools.BuildTasks.RunPythonCommand.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Python Tools\Microsoft.PythonTools.Django.targets   64  6   DjangoWebProject1

Can someone tell me what is wrong? Here is what the Microsoft.PythonTools.DJango.targets file has:

```
  <Target Name="ResolveStaticUrlSetting" DependsOnTargets="ResolvePythonInterpreterPath">
<RunPythonCommand Target="import $(DjangoSettingsModule) as settings; print(settings.STATIC_URL)"
                  TargetType="code"
                  ExecuteIn="none"
                  WorkingDirectory="$(QualifiedProjectHome)"
                  ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
  <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="DjangoStaticUrlSetting" />
</RunPythonCommand>

<Message Text="DjangoStaticUrlSetting=$(DjangoStaticUrlSetting)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is happened to me too.
In my case, I was solved it by entering "Path environment variable" from Configure of "Python Environments".

Comment: I entered "PYTHONPATH" in this field under the python environment configuration and it worked. By default the "Path environment variable" is blank.